# How can I convert a pandas dataframe to an csv file without getting the UnicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tkinter

I am trying to export a pandas dataframe to a csv file using the to_csv() as:

```
export_file_path=fd.asksaveasfile(filetypes=[("CSV File","*.csv"),("All Files","*.*")],defaultextension="*.csv",initialdir=fDir,initialfile="Untitled")
if export_file_path:
    df.to_csv(export_file_path)
```

Getting this error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2640' in
>   position 13: character maps to

Comment: try `df.to_csv(export_file_path, encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: @Gravity Mass  I read from the documentation that by default the encoding is **'utf-8'** . Therefore , I am still getting the same error

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: which line makes problem ? You have it in full error message. Did you check in Google what char has code '\u2640' ? Maybe problem is in different place then you expect. Maybe problem makes filename or when you display some inforation on screen - some systems has problem to display data in UTF-8

Comment: @samyakagarwal like @furas says, post full error message. Put the `df.to_csv(export_file_path)` in `try` and `except` block and print the file names or paths in `except` so that you can look into the file specifically. If a file contains no character in a place like this: "" even utf-8 won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Error occurs because you are not specifying the encoding

Try this:

`df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')`